# Indy FTP on Android fails under Delphi Seattle

Tags: android, delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-10-seattle

I created a multi platform (win32 and Android) application using the Indy FTP component to download and upload one file. During development under Win32 everything works reproducibly correct. The file is down and uploaded. 
Under Android I get an eidconnectionclosedgracefully exception.
I know that this means that the server obviously closed the connection, but what is the difference when using win32 or Android?
In the following code:

```
      ftpdate := FTP.FileDate('notizen.txt');
      FTP.Get('notizen.txt', tempdir + 'notizen.txt', true, false);
```

retrieving the file date under Android still works correctly, so the connection obviously is established, but the subsequent get command fails. I use passive mode and ftbinary transfer type set in the component editor.

Are there any special issues under Android I have to care about?

Comment: How large is your file?  Do you have the `TIdFTP.NATKeepAlive` property enabled?  Is your Android device connected to the network using WiFi or Cellular? Remember that FTP uses multiple socket connections, so it is usually the case that the main command connection may get disconnected due to idle timeouts by FTP-unaware proxies/routers while a long data transfer is in progress on another connection.

Comment: The file is only 2k and it takes only a glimpse under windows.

Comment: I wonder if it is a threading issue? Has the file transfer to happen in the main UI thread?

Comment: You did not answer my other questions. Also, have you tried sniffing the network traffic to figure out which connection is being closed and why? In any case, `TIdFTP` is not a multi-threaded component. Everything it does operates in whatever thread calls into it. But you definitely should *NOT* use it in the main UI thread on Android.